# Call function from AngularJs Directive for Dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dropzone.js

I've this directive for the dropzone.js script: [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/compact/8118670/)

This works fine but I want call the function processQueue() with a button.
But I can't find how I can call this function!

Comment: Can you post an example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried to access the variable "dropzone" in the directive (dropzone = new Dropzone...) but I don't now how I can do this , I'm pretty new in Angularjs.
I checked , and the function is present  in this object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by myself, juste add this line in the end of the directive :

```
scope.dropzone = dropzone;
```

And next you can call the function like that :

```
$scope.dropzone.processQueue();
```