# Dropzonejs and Ionic, can't choose between gallery and camera

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, dropzone.js

I'm trying to implement [dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com) into an Ionic app.

I've done this before on a AngularJS webapp, when I accessed this site on mobile I could choose between taking a picture or getting one from the gallery of my device.

With Ionic I've implemented dropzonejs the same way, however I'm redirected straight to the gallery of my device instead of presenting me an option to choose between the camera and the gallery.

Could this be some kind of security (I'm using Android for testing atm)? Should I add some config to allow pictures to be taken?
Or does it just don't work in Ionic, any other directives to use?

Thanks in advance!

Here's my code :

Controller:

```
  /**
         * DropZone config
         */

        angular.extend($scope, $state, {
          dropzoneConfig: {
            'options': {
              autoProcessQueue    : false,
              maxFilesize         : 10,
              maxFiles            : 10,
              parallelUploads     : 10,
              paramName           : "photo",
              url                 : 'https://xxxxxxx.xx/api/photo/add'
            },
            'eventHandlers': {
              'addedfile': function (file) {
                $scope.hasPhoto = true
              },
              'sending': function(file, xhr, formData) {},
              'success': function(file, response) {
                console.log('Photos uploaded');
              },
              'queuecomplete': function (file) {
                alert('succes');
              }
            }
          }

        });
```

Directive :

```
angular.module('as.directives')
  .directive('dropzone', function() {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var config, dropzone;

      config = scope[attrs.dropzone];

      // create a Dropzone for the element with the given options
      dropzone = new Dropzone(element[0], config.options);

      // bind the given event handlers
      angular.forEach(config.eventHandlers, function (handler, event) {
        dropzone.on(event, handler);

        // Added this line so we can call $scope.dropzone.processQueue();
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614980/call-function-from-angularjs-directive-for-dropzone-js

        scope.dropzone = dropzone;

      });
    };
  });
```